# Gulp-browserify Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browserify

I am pretty new to `gulp` and `browserify`. I have written a `gulpfile.js` like this.

```
gulp.task('default', function (done) {


var b = browserify({
            entries: ['app/app.js'],
        });


var browserifiedCode = b
        .transform(bulkify)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) {
            gutil.log('Browserify Error', gutil.colors.red(err));
            gutil.beep();
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('app.browserified.js'))  --> what does it mean ??
        .pipe(buffer());

var nonBrowserifyLibraries = [];        
var output = gulpMerge(
        gulp.src(nonBrowserifyLibraries),
        browserifiedCode
    )
    .pipe(concat('app.js'));

//output = output.pipe(uglify());

return output.pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

After running `gulp` it is creating `app.js` but when I am running it in browser then I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function`

Can any one help me out.

Thanks

EDITED : I am using `bulk-require` which somewhere has `fs.readdirSync(abc)` , I am sure it is creating a problem. 
Even without gulp when I did `browserify app/app.js -o app.js` and loaded this `app.js` in browser still I got the same `fs.readdirSync` error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet, specific for only browserify task.

```
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
return browserify('app/app.js') // main source file
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app.js')); // destination file
});
```

Comment: no it didn't work out .. I have updated my question with new findings.